# Why is my code not printing what I need it to?

Tags: java, arrays

The task is to find the median and if the input is over 10 integers then it needs to print: "Data items past number 10 ignored" but it's not doing that, what is wrong with my code preventing it from printing?

**My code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Median {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int MAX_INPUTS = 10;
        int[] numbers = new int[MAX_INPUTS];
        int count = 0;
        int input;
// Read input until a negative number is encountered or the maximum number of inputs is reached
        while (count < MAX_INPUTS) {
       input = scnr.nextInt();

            if (input < 0) {
                break;
            }

            // Check if count exceeds the maximum allowed inputs before recording the number
            numbers[count] = input;
            count++;
        }

        // Check if no data entered
        if (count == 0) {
            System.out.println("No data entered.");
            return;
        }

        // Calculate the median
        double median;

        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            int middle1 = numbers[count / 2 - 1];
            int middle2 = numbers[count / 2];
            median = (double) (middle1 + middle2) / 2;
        } else {
            median = numbers[count / 2];
        }

       ** // Display the result
        if (count > MAX_INPUTS) {
            System.out.println("Data items past number 10 ignored");
        }
        System.out.println("Median: " + median);**
    }
}
```

**Input:
1 2 3 4 5 60 70 80 90 100 110 120 130 -100

Your output:
Median: 32.5

Expected output:
Data items past number 10 ignored
Median: 32.5**

I don't know why it won't print "Data items past number 10 ignored"?

Comment: Your loop only (tries to) read in a maximum of 10 numbers, so how can `if (count > MAX_INPUTS) {` ever be true?

Comment: Problems like this are easily found using the debugger that comes with your IDE. Put a breakpoint on the `if (count > MAX_INPUTS)` line and see what the value of `count` is.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not giving your scanner an opportunity to go past the max inputs.
If you want it to go past you'll need to put your if statements within the while loop.

```
while (input > 0 && count > MAX_INPUTS)
```